# What is this "trick" to solve for the unknowns in partial fractions?

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

> For example, $\frac{4}{(x-2)(x+7)} = \frac{A}{x+7} + \frac{B}{x-2}$

setting the numerator: $4= A(x-2) + B(x+7) $

The method I always use is to expand and compare coefficients, which can be very long if it is a more complicated fraction.

However, to solve this very quickly, we can take $x=2$ and therefore $A = -4/9$

and $x= -7$ and therefore $B=4/9$

What is this trick and when can I use it? I've not learnt this, but I've seen many people do this trick to solve integral partial fractions very quickly. Can I get some examples on when can I use it and how to determine it as I've heard that we cannot use this for every situation.

For partial fractions, I've learnt about

Linear: $Q(x) = ax+b : \frac{A}{ax+b}$

Irreducible/Quadratic: $Q(x) = ax^2 + bx+c : \frac{Ax+B}{ax^2 +bx+c}$

Comment: If two polynomials are equal then they are also equal after evaluating at any specific point $x$ and you are choosing the values of $x$ which are convenient.

Comment: When you use partial fractions, you end up with an equality between polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$. It must hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so you can substitute particular values of $x$ to find the constants more easily.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek What do you mean by "equal polynomials"

Comment: $4$ is a polynomial.  Your equation says it equals A(x-2)+B(x+7)$ which is another polynomial.

Comment: After you have a result you can always verify it by calculation, so you can always decide easily whether you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a name for the trick.  The original equation comes with a hidden $x \neq 2,-7$ because of the denominator so you are technically taking the limit as $x \to 2$.  You got it backwards in your post-when you substitute in $x=2$ you get the value for $B$ because the $A(x-2)$ goes to zero.

Another way would be to substitute any two other values for $x$.  You would get two simultaneous equations for $A,B$.  Using $2,-7$ is convenient because the equations decouple.

Comment: from what I've seen in the comments and here, when equating 2 polynomials which we always do in solving for unknowns in partial fractions, we can set x to be a value that eliminates (A for example), so we can find B. When does this method not work?

Comment: If you are working in the reals you could have a coefficient of $A$ that has no real roots.

Comment: Technically at first you might consider we need to take a limit, but if two real polynomials are equal at all but at most two (or at most finitely many) numbers, then they are equal at all numbers, so we can set $x=2$ legitimately without having to speak of limits at $2$ in that calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are referring to the [Heaviside cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method)! In your case, you can multiply both sides of the equation by $(x+7)$. Setting $x = -7$ eliminates B and solves directly for A. This works for ${most}$ of the linear terms that you mention. For the irreducible terms, you may have to compare coefficients.

If you had all linear terms and one irreducible term, you could use this method to solve for all the linear terms, then solve the other term algebraically.